# Create view from table with multiple primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-view

I've a table like this one:

```
Column          |         Type          | Modifiers


 username       | character varying(12) | not null

 electioncode   | integer               | not null

 votes          | integer               | default 0


PRIMARY KEY (username, electioncode)
```

i need to create a view with username, electioncode, max(votes)
if i use this query it works fine but without username:

**SELECT electioncode, max(votes) from table group by electioncode;**

if i add username it asks me to add it into the group by but if i do that it gives me the entire table instead of just the username-electioncode-maxvotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get username associated with this number of votes? Or any username in given election code?

If the first:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON ( electioncode )
    *
FROM table
ORDER BY electioncode, votes desc;
```

if the other:

```
SELECT
    electioncode,
    min(username),
    max(votes)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY electioncode;
```

Comment: The first is perfect, thanks a lot to you, to who edited the question and anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your username field seems to be unique. Every record has different username (I am assuming) thus when you group by username it will give you all the records. What you are trying to do has a logic issue not syntax issue.

A suggestion: You want to write on a piece of paper the output you would like to see and then construct the query... If you want Username, Electioncode and max (votes) then imagine how you would display the data where two usernames - user1 and user 2 who have electioncode 001 and voted 1 each? How would you display this?